# Are low level spells cast with higher level slots considered to be a spell of that level for all game effects? (For just that cast)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature

When casting a lower level spell with a higher level spell slot, does that spell become that level for the casting or is it still considered a first level spell?

I'm specifically looking at the **Disciple Of Life** rule where the healing is 2 + the spell's level. If you cast good berry with a level 9 slot would it heal 12 hp per berry instead of 4 for being a level 1 spell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *goodberry* will heal 12 hp per berry if cast using a 9th level slot.

> When
>   a
>   spellcaster
>   casts
>   a
>   spell
>   using
>   a
>   slot
>   that
>   is
>   of
>   a
>   higher
>   level
>   than
>   the
>   spell,
>   the
>   spell
>   assumes
>   the
>   higher
>   level
>   for
>   that
>   casting.
>   For
>   instance,
>   if
>   Umara
>   casts
>   *magic
>   missile*
>   using
>   one
>   of
>   her
>   2nd‑level
>   slots,
>   that
>   *magic
>   missile*
>   is
>   2nd
>   level.
>   Effectively,
>   the
>   spell
>   expands
>   to
>   fill
>   the
>   slot
>   it
>   is
>   put
>   into.

So if you cast *goodberry* with a 9th level spell slot, it will be a 9th level spell, and Disciple of Life will treat it as such.